# Powershell New-ScheduledTaskAction - with inline command

Tags: powershell

Im trying to create a scheduled task on a VM but with the actual command (Powershell command) within the task itself.

Here's what I have:

```
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date) -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 3)
 
 $task = @{
    Action   = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell.exe" "-Command 'Get-Service -Name "Tssdis" | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Stopped"} | Restart-Service'"
    Trigger  = $trigger
    User     = "admin"
    TaskName = 'tssdis-restart'
    Description = 'Respawn tssdis process in event of failure'
    RunLevel    = 'Highest'
}

Register-ScheduledTask @task

Get-ScheduledTask | where{$_.TaskPath -eq "\"} 
Get-Service -Name "Tssdis"
```

The task is added correctly - we can see that, but whenever I stop the tssdis process, it doesn't come backup.

The problem is the perhaps:

1. The syntax of the command itself within the Action variable. I'm not sure if that's correct. Or
2. The Syntax of the username -> Am I meant to give the syntax as DOMAIN\admin? If so, where can I find the DOMAIN name of that user?

I tried to change the double quotes to single quotes in the Command line.
I tried also to change the User variable to User     = "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" - that didn't work either

Comment: Check the Event Viewer on the machine to see why it doesn't stop.  Most likely a child process wasn't stopped.  Make sure when you stop tssdis that all child processes also get stopped.

Comment: Thanks - do you see anything wrong with my method/script?

Comment: No.  There are lots of reasons a process fails to start and cannot remotely determine your issue with no debug info.

Comment: You're trying to have one set of doublequotes inside another.  The programs args I get is `-Command 'Get-Service -Name`.  The syntax coloring shows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to have one set of doublequotes inside another. The programs args I get in task scheduler is `-Command 'Get-Service -Name`. The other quoted part becomes the working directory.  The syntax coloring shows the quoting.

```
$task.action

Id               :
Arguments        : -Command 'Get-Service -Name
Execute          : powershell.exe
WorkingDirectory : Tssdis | Where-Object {.Status -eq Stopped} | Restart-Service'
PSComputerName   :
```

I assume the admin user exists.  Note this runs every three minutes.

One way to re-quote it is to only use the single quotes in where-object.  The get-service argument doesn't need quotes.

```
Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell.exe" "-Command Get-Service -Name Tssdis | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq 'Stopped'} | Restart-Service"
```

Or using the other version of where-object lets you drop all singlequotes:

```
Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell.exe" "-Command Get-Service -Name Tssdis | Where-Object Status -eq Stopped | Restart-Service"
```